# Raster will not export in QGIS or ArcMap, therefore won't clip, georeference, or work in raster calc

Tags: qgis, raster, arcmap, export

I have a DEM raster file that will not export in QGIS or ArcMap, in QGIS I right click, export, save as and the file that loads has nothing that pops on the map, the values listed go from an extreme low number to an extreme high number but nothing pops up on the map. The export takes a while to render but nothing shows up.

I also cannot clip it, georeference it,  use it in raster calculator, or warp it in either program.

What might be the problem and how might it be solved?

(I went back through the code and typed "input file" and output file" so as to simplify and not to give personal info.) when I try to clip it the log messages are as follows:

---

QGIS version: 3.16.8-Hannover
QGIS code revision: 8c50902e
Qt version: 5.15.2
GDAL version: 3.3.0
GEOS version: 3.9.1-CAPI-1.14.2
PROJ version: Rel. 8.0.1, March 5th, 2021
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'Clip raster by mask layer' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'ALPHA_BAND' : False, 'CROP_TO_CUTLINE' : True, 'DATA_TYPE' : 0, 'EXTRA' : '', 'INPUT' : '*inputfile*.img', 'KEEP_RESOLUTION' : False, 'MASK' : 'box_try.shp', 'MULTITHREADING' : False, 'NODATA' : None, 'OPTIONS' : '', 'OUTPUT' : '*outputfile*.img', 'SET_RESOLUTION' : False, 'SOURCE_CRS' : None, 'TARGET_CRS' : None, 'X_RESOLUTION' : None, 'Y_RESOLUTION' : None }

GDAL command:
gdalwarp -of HFA -cutline box_try.shp -cl box_try -crop_to_cutline *inputfile*.img
*outputfile*.img
GDAL command output:
Copying raster attribute table from *inputfile*.img to new file.

Creating output file that is 8317P x 6344L.

Processing *inputfile*.img [1/1] : 0ERROR 4: Unable to open external data file: *inputfile*.ige

ERROR 1: *inputfile*.img, band 1: IReadBlock failed at X offset 601, Y offset 531: Unable to open external data file: *inputfile*.ige

Using internal nodata values (e.g. -3.40282e+38) for image *inputfile*.img.

Copying nodata values from source *inputfile*.img to destination *outputfile*.

Execution completed in 1.04 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': *outputfile*.img'}

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'Clip raster by mask layer' finished

Comment: I suggest you provide more information and ideally add a screenshot. Otherwise, it could be difficult to help.

Answer (score 1):

From the log message:

```
Unable to open external data file: inputfile.ige
```

Either the filename is wrong, the file is not present, or you did not give GDAL the full path to the folder it is stored in.

Comment: I went back through the code and typed "input file" and "output file" so as not to give out personal information, i should have mentioned that

Comment: Agreed, but according to the error message GDAL can not find that input file.